# Why does my code run into an infinite loop?

Tags: python-2.7, loops

```
import sys
keyword = raw_input("enter a keyword ").lower()
key_phrase = raw_input("enter a key phrase").lower()
key_phrase_length = len(key_phrase)

character_position = []
for character in keyword:
    if character in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        position = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".find(character) + 1
        character_position.append(position)


cycle = -1
new_keyword = ""
if len(keyword) < len(key_phrase):
    while len(keyword) < len(key_phrase):

        cycle += 1
        if cycle >= len(keyword):
                cycle = 0
        new_keyword = new_keyword + keyword[cycle]
        sys.stdout.write(new_keyword[cycle])
```

above is my code, when entering a keyword such as "cat", and a key phrase such as "computing", the code should print the letters of the "cat" to the length of the word computing. however this runs into a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a loop `while len(keyword) < len(key_phrase):` whose iteration depends on `keyword` and `key_prase`, but you do not change these variables in the loop body, so once it is entered, the loop condition will always evaluate to `True`, so you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

In short, in this loop:

```
while len(keyword) < len(key_phrase)
```

you never update or change either `keyword` or `key_phrase`. Since they never update or change, the escape condition will never be met